# Want a paddle at bottom x-axis in this animation

Tags: css, html, canvas

I am making an animation of ball and paddle. Ball is bouncing well.
After this i want a paddle or a `<div>` element shaped "paddle" at x-axis.
This paddle must be moving only by x-axis and should be moving when i active cursor at any position to x-axis.
Any help?

Here is my code:

```
var x=150;
var y=150;
var dx=2;
var dy=4;
var WIDTH;
var HEIGHT;

var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,150,10,0,2*Math.PI,true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

function init() {
  var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(draw,10);
}
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,2*Math.PI,true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
  bounce();
}
function bounce(){
  if(x+dx>300||x+dx<0)
    dx=-dx;
  if(y+dy>300||y+dy<0)
    dy=-dy;
}
init();
```

[And in a Fiddle, here.](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/xWvEU/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

In your var declarations:

```
var mouseX = 150;
```

In your `init()` function:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler);
```

In your `draw()` function:

```
ctx.rect(mouseX-20,280,40,5); // rect( x , y , width , height )
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';      //       ^ This is the mouse's X position, minus half the paddle width.
ctx.fill();
```

And finally, add this function:

```
function moveHandler(e){
  e = e || window.event; // Compatibility.
  mouseX = e.offsetX;
}
```

---

So, your resulting code **[Will look like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QnFg3/1/)**:

```
var x=150;
var y=150;
var dx=2;
var dy=4;
var WIDTH;
var HEIGHT;
var mouseX = 150;
var mouseY;

var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,150,10,0,2*Math.PI,true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

function init() {
  document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler);
  return setInterval(draw,10);
}
function moveHandler(e){
  mouseX = e.offsetX;
}
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.rect(mouseX-20,280,40,5);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,2*Math.PI,true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
  bounce();
}
function bounce(){
  if(x+dx>300||x+dx<0)
    dx=-dx;
  if(y+dy>300||y+dy<0)
    dy=-dy;
}
init();
```